# How to convert Text(with breakline) to display properly on HTML textbox

Tags: html

```
Kemandirian spesies ialah keupayaan haiwan dan tumbuhan untuk mengekalkan spesiesnya bagi mengelakkan kepupusan.
Ciri dan tingkah laku khas haiwan untuk melindungi diri daripada musuh seperti:
(i) Memutuskan anggota badan;
(ii) Menyembur dakwat hitam;
(iii) Mempunyai mata palsu.
Galakkan penggunaan TMK untuk membuat pemerhatian pelbagai ciri dan tingkah laku khas haiwan untuk melindungi diri.
```

let's say that i have this text and i save it to database , but when i tried to pull it out from database , it just show everything in a single line , what's is the best way to keep the original format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change all \n characters to <br> and then upload to your DB.
When you fetch your data then you can convert all the <br> tags to \n character.

```js
let x = `Kemandirian spesies ialah keupayaan haiwan dan tumbuhan untuk mengekalkan spesiesnya bagi mengelakkan kepupusan.
Ciri dan tingkah laku khas haiwan untuk melindungi diri daripada musuh seperti:
(i) Memutuskan anggota badan;
(ii) Menyembur dakwat hitam;
(iii) Mempunyai mata palsu.
Galakkan penggunaan TMK untuk membuat pemerhatian pelbagai ciri dan tingkah laku khas haiwan untuk melindungi diri.`;

let withBR = x.replace(/\n/gm, "<br>");
console.log("Upload To DB \n\n");
console.log(withBR);

// Upload To The DB

// ----------------------------------------------------------

// On Fetch Starts

let originalText = withBR.replace(/\<br\>/gm, "\n")
console.log("Original Text \n\n");
console.log(originalText);
```

Hope it helps.